# Calculating neighboring corners in a mesh

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, mesh, face

[image]

Given a mesh with vertices listed above (vertices were added in order to create a triangle, then V3 and V4 splitting the triangle into 2 faces, F0, F1).

If a corner is defined by a vertex index paired with a face index, so Ci = (vertexIndex, faceIndex) or c0 = [0, 1], c4 = [2, 0], etc.

How can we calculate the next corner within a given face in the clockwise motion?

For example:

```
next(C0) returns C2
next(C6) returns C9
next(C9) returns C0
next(C4) returns C10
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that WebGL meshes don't support quadrilaterals, only triangles. So any geometry you build or import into Three.js is not going to have a face with four sides like `F1`. How are you splitting the triangle?

Comment: In this scenario, the user input will be adding lines that will split the faces, so they could be in any shape or orientation. I use the term "Face" loosely here. I imagine I will have to create a geometry for each F0, F1...Fn since there is no guarantee that the split face can be formed with 3 points.